# calculation of an immensely large modulus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, factorial

I have to calculate modulus of
$$
\frac{(7 \times 2017)!}{7^{2017}}\mod7
$$

however i have no clue how to do this.
My assumption is that since both are multiplicatives of 7 that the result will be zero. However i have no way no back this up.

Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: The first question is, how many times is $(7 \times 2017)!$ divisible by $7$?

Comment: $$
(7\times 2017)! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 7 \cdot \ldots \cdot 14 \cdot \ldots \cdot 49 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2017 \cdot \ldots \cdot (7\times 2017)
$$

Comment: 7 is the modulus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the numerator we have $2017$ numbers that are divisible by $7$ , but already $49$ is even divisible by $7^2$. Hence the exponent with respect to $7$ is larger than $2017$, which means that the fraction is divisible by $7$. Hence, the result is $0$. Note that your argument need not work (it would fail if the sevens would cancel out completely or the fraction would not be an integer)